# Objective-C - Where to prompt in UIAlertView on view controller dismissal

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

When I close a view controller, I want to prompt the user for input.  This input is necessary before the dismiss should actually take place.

I tried placing the following code in my view controller:

```
-(void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion
{
    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello!" message:@"Please enter your name:" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Continue" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    UITextField * alertTextField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
    alertTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    alertTextField.placeholder = @"Enter your name";
    [alert show];

    [super dismissViewControllerAnimated:flag completion:completion];
}
```

However, since the UIAlertView does not block and wait, the super call gets executed.

I was debating on removing the super call from this function, and moving it to the alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex: function.  I guess I would then need to store the flag and completion variables that are passed into the dismissViewControllerAnimated in the first place, so that I would have them available in the alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex: function.

Is there a better approach, so that I do not have to store these parameter values for the super call?

Comment: Have you tried calling it in viewWillDisappear?

Comment: You need to refactor your code. Call the alert before attempting to dismiss the view controller. Only actually dismiss the view controller once the alert view has been successfully dismissed with the needed data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, I dont see why you could not put the call to dismiss in alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex.  You could just set the flag parameter to YES or NO, and the completion block parameter to nil.

Of course, this does require prompting the user with UIAlertView before they have actually attempted to dismiss the view controller.

Answer (score 1):

You should intercept the close request before `dismissViewControllerAnimated:` is called and use that to prevent the call from being made and to show the alert instead. Then, in the alert delegate method call `dismissViewControllerAnimated:` on `self`. Don't try cutting out `super` and calling it later, it will get messy and be a pain to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

You could try making a new method, ala:

```
-(void) dismissButtonPressed
{
    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello!" message:@"Please enter your name:" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Continue" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    UITextField * alertTextField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
    alertTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    alertTextField.placeholder = @"Enter your name";
    [alert show];
}
```

Then call that method when your dismiss button is pressed (done in different ways depending upon whether you are creating your views programmatically or in Interface Builder). Then, only when the UIAlertView is dismissed
(i.e. in `-(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex`) you dismiss the view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Create the `UIAlertView` on the `button` you press to dismiss now and in the `delegate` methods of the `UIAlertView` you deal with the input you need , when you get what you want , simply `dismiss` the `viewcontroller`.